# Pushing objects through pipeline on stream end event (or "Error: stream.push() after EOF")

Tags: node.js

I have a nodejs stream pipeline that is a bit like this:

```
source.pipe(bulkElasticSearchLookup).pipe(doWork).pipe(destination)
```

The purpose of bulkElasticSearchLookup is to collect incoming objects, and when it has 10, to make a bulk search in Elasticsearch for all 10, and then to make 10 individual this.push() calls to get the items into the doWork transform.

This reduces the number of calls I make to Elasticsearch by a factor of 10, making my pipe line about 4 times faster.

Here is the code:

```
EsBulkLookup.prototype._transform = function (chunk, encoding, callback) {

    var self = this;

    self.queue.push(chunk);
    if (self.queue.length === self.bulkSize) {
        var lookups = self._doLookups();
        self._pushAll(lookups);
        self.queue = [];
    }
    callback()
};

EsBulkLookup.prototype._pushAll = function (items) {
    var self = this;
    items.forEach(function (item) {
        self.push(item);
    });
};
```

When the stream ends, there might be a few items in self.queue, so I want to flush these to the next step in the pipeline.

I tried this:

```
var self = this;
this.on('end', function () {
    var lookups = self._doLookups();
    self._pushAll(lookups);
});
```

And that gives me:

```
Error: stream.push() after EOF
```

How can I flush items from my Transform to the next stage in the pipeline when the stream ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text of my question contained a clue: "flush".

From https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_transform_flush_callback

> transform._flush(callback)
>
> callback Function Call this function (optionally with an error argument) when you are done flushing any remaining data.

```
EsBulkLookup.prototype._flush = function (callback) {
    var lookups = this._doLookups();
    this._pushAll(lookups);
};
```